# Copy contact to outlook contacts folder

Tags: ruby, outlook

I am trying to copy all contacts from the GAL into a personal contacts folder. I have managed to list all the GAL contacts using the ruby script below:

```
require 'win32ole'
outlook = WIN32OLE.new('Outlook.Application')
mapi = outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
gal = mapi.Session.AddressLists('Global Address List')
copy = mapi.Session.AddressLists('Copy')

gal.AddressEntries.each{|address|
  contact = address.GetExchangeUser
  next unless contact

  ## what do I do here to copy this contact to 'copy'??
}
```

I know the advantages of the GAL, I know about the offline address book, but I want number recognition and group-based blocking abilities on my phone; for these the contacts must reside in a regular contacts group. If anyone knows a cheap of free product that does the same, I'm also open to trying that.

Comment: *## what do I do here??* - what you want to there ?

Comment: I want to copy the contact to the address list in 'copy'